# YAML Editor. Suggestions?

Tags: editor, yaml

I am looking for a convenient way to write and edit YAML.
Right now I am using: http://editor.swagger.io/#/
But it is not so convenient because when you have too many lines you are getting lost there.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Notepad++ it will automatically do identation for you and you can also find out your code lines very easily.I don't whether it supports YAML or not.
Second, You can use Sublime it 
`Sublime Text 2` also supports YAML files with syntax highlighting and indentation right out of the box. If you have tabs as your default use for indentation in Sublime Text, Jon Thomas over at Coder Wall explains how to fix this. I've copied what he wrote below for your convenience:

Languages like YAML require text to be indented using spaces. Tabs are not allowed. So, if you typically use Sublime Text 2 with tabs as your default indentation, here's how you can force a certain language to always use spaces. I'll use a .yml file as an example, but you can follow the same steps for any file type.

While editing a .yml file in Sublime Text 2, go to the Sublime Text 2 menu. 
`

```
Go to Preferences -> Settings - More -> Syntax Specifc` - User
Sublime Text 2
```

will open a settings file specific to the language you chose to edit settings for. In this case, I'll be editing the YAML.sublime-settings file, which will apply settings to only the YAML syntax language.
Use the following code to set up your indentation settings:

```
"tab_size": 2,
"translate_tabs_to_spaces": true
```

3.You can try ORM Designer. It's a visual editor for ERD model with support for import/export to YAML files.